# Remote server returned an unexpected response. (413) Requested entity too large

Tags: wcf

I am consuming wcf service in Wpf application. I have to save an image which is 185 Kb in size. Problem is every time, i try to save it i got this message

Remote server returned an unexpected response. (413) Requested entity too large.

Here is my binding on client side

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IHRMEmployeeDef" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483646"
         maxBufferSize="2147483646" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483646" >
<readerQuotas maxDepth="525288" maxStringContentLength="525288" maxArrayLength="525288"
                   maxBytesPerRead="525288" maxNameTableCharCount="525288" />
</binding>
```

AND

```
 <endpoint address="http://localhost:1714/PAYROLL/Setup/HRMEmployeeDef.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IHRMEmployeeDef"
            contract="Service_EmployeeDef.IHRMEmployeeDef" name="BasicHttpBinding_IHRMEmployeeDef" />
```

Any Suggestions

Comment: You need to increase the maxItemsinobjectgraph property in service behavior under webconfig.

Comment: <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />

Comment: Thats maxitemsinobjectgraph size

Comment: I doubt is it something to do with IIS settings?

Comment: The problem here is you are sending large amount of data. try to add paging .

Comment: Ok... Where can i set paging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution... By setting maxReceivedMessageSize In my Web.Config